# Assigning variable number of return values to a function call

Tags: python

I have a function that returns values based on `if/elifs`. I am trying to call that function, however, when I do, I get too many arguments, since each `if` contains 3 return values, but there are 4 unique return values in total. How do I assign the return values to the function call? I tried `if series_picker.series` but I can't grab the variable like that. The questions I looked at didn't have this level of complexity to them or were about recursion.

```
def series_picker():
    series = input("Which series would you like to choose?\n'Country' or 'US State'\n")
    if series == 'Country':
        country = input('Which country would you like to look at?\n')
        df = daily_framer(path1)
        df = df.loc[df['Country'] == country].reset_index().drop(['level_1'], axis=1).rename(columns={'level_0': 'Date'})
        df['Confirmed Difference'] = df['Confirmed'].diff()
        df['Death Difference'] = df['Deaths'].diff()
        return df, series, country
    elif series == 'US State':
        state = input('Which US State would you like to look at?\n')
        df = daily_framer(path2)
        df = df.loc[df['State'] == state].reset_index().drop(['level_1'], axis=1).rename(columns={'level_0': 'Date'})
        df['Confirmed Difference'] = df['Confirmed'].diff()
        df['Death Difference'] = df['Deaths'].diff()
        return df, series, state

df, series, country, state = series_picker()
```

Comment: `return df, series, country, None` and `return df, series, None, state`?

Comment: This works. char limit